# embeded php code in html5

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to embed some php code in a .html file but it doesn't seem to work. I read that in order for this to work the file has to be saved with the .php extension, but when I do that and open it up in a browser the browser just displays all my code. What am I doing wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Welcome</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <?php
        $x = 3;
        $y = 2;
        $ans = $x + $y;
    ?> 
    <h1 style = "text-align: center;"> The answer is: <?php= $ans ?> </h1>
    <section class="loginform cf">
        <form name="start page" action="index_submit" method="get" accept-charset="utf-8">

            <label style = "text-align: center;" >What type of property?</label>

            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <input type="button" value = "Commercial" onClick="parent.location='commercial.html'">

            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <input type="button" value = "Residential" onClick="parent.location='residential.html'">

        </form>     
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your browser doesn't understand PHP. What you need to do is upload your file to a web server that knows what to do with it. Most commercial web hosts are set up this way. Alternatively, you can set up a server on your own computer. If you search the web for LAMP + PHP (or perhaps WAMP if you're using Windows), you should find instructions on what to do next.

In the server, files with names ending in `.php` are handled by a PHP server module, which looks for code between the `<?php` and `?>` tags and executes it before sending the results on to the browser that requested the page.

Comment: Even the search `XAMPP` will do ;) And it's not the browser that has to understand what PHP is, it's the web server.

Comment: @dbf Precisely. So you need a server that knows what PHP is. (Wait a minute, didn't I just say that..?)

Comment: Okaaay.... are you trying to tell me there's something wrong with that statement?

Answer (score 0):

Your php code will not work with .html; Change file extension to .php.
You should run your php code from the server. You can download [AppServ](http://www.appservnetwork.com/) or [WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com/en/)